# background-color not extending to the entire element

Tags: html, css, background-color

```css
This is my CSS code:
#outer {
  width:580px;
  padding:10px;
  float:left;
}
  .inner {
  width:560px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color:#fff;
  color:#666666;
}
```

```html
And the HTML:
<div id="outer">
  <div class="inner">
   ... a lot of content
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is the background-color for the inner div doesn't extend to fill the entire div alongside its content. I've had this problem quite often, and my solution has usually been to specify a height for `#inner`, which makes the background fill `#inner` accordingly. However, I don't want to specify a height explicitly because it's dynamic content. What should I do to make the background-color fill the div as it extends?

Comment: Is your code really as simple as this? Are you talking about the white (`#fff`) background? And does your `div.inner` contain floating elements?

Comment: I just adjusted the code; I copied and pasted, and the background-color of .inner doesn't extend normally as it should, it doesn't even show, unless I explicitly specify a height.

Comment: I don't understand your question, and giving your background a #fff value over a white background makes it even more difficult to understand. Could you please try something with different colors where you ACTUALLY CAN REPLICATE the issue? What you mention is the default behavior, so you really must have something there. See, I made a fiddle with LOTS of content (not 3 words) using your EXACT code and still couldn't replicate your issue. See http://jsfiddle.net/mas66adm/

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't replicate your issue. If you don't specify a height for '.inner', the background color should extend dynamically as '.inner' fills with content.

You might be having an issue due to a lack of a CSS reset. Each browser has a set of standard css rules it applies to all pages, unless you override these rules.

I recommend adding a CSS reset in your  above all your current css.
A very basic but popular reset is by Eric Meyer, found here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Let me know if that helps, and if not try posting an image of what you are experiencing.

Btw, this is how your code renders for me:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Alex. I already apply reset styles. But I replace them with those you specified and still got the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set the position of each element, with the inner element needing to be absolute, and then just tell the inner div to always fill the outer one with height: 100%. The only care that you have to take with this is that setting the position of inner to absolute will then make it ignore floats, but presumably you are taking care of that with outer.

(I changed the background color to red in this answer to make it more obvious what is going on.)

```css
This is my CSS code:
#outer {
  position: relative;
  width:960px;
  height: 500px;
}
.inner {
  position:absolute; 
  height:100%;
  width:400px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
And the HTML:
<div id="outer">
  <div class="inner">
   ... a lot of content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew, Your solution works fine, but it's messing with other elements which come after .inner, and which are still contained within #outer, since I'm setting .inner's height at 100%;

Comment: Can you use JavaScript to calculate the proper height? So grab the height of the outer one, the heights of all the inners ones, and then the height of this inner one would be the hight of the outer minus the height of the other inners? Or do you only want to use CSS?

Answer (score 0):

The padding of the outer element will always show the background color of the outer element...

Just remove the padding there.

```
#outer {
  width:580px;
  /* padding: 10px;*/
  background:red;
  border:1px solid green;
}
  .inner {
  width:560px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color:lightblue;
  color:#666666;
}
```